# Join several pdf files 4 on 1 page

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

### Issue

I want to join several pdf files to a single pdf with 4 pages on one page and continuously proceeding pages using just one SINGLE tex file. Something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper]
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{page1.pdf}
\includepdf{page2.pdf}
\includepdf{page3.pdf}
\includepdf{page4.pdf}
\end{document}
```

but `pdfpages` seems to stay in conflict with `pgfpages`.

### Until now

So far I always used two tex files:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{page1.pdf}
\includepdf{page2.pdf}
\includepdf{page3.pdf}
\includepdf{page4.pdf}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x2]{temp.pdf}
\end{document}
```

### Condition

I do not want to use [pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam) as it does almost the same as pdfpages.

### Update

Is there a way to generalize this also to different layout like `nup=2x3`? `6 to 1` is undefined in `\pgfpagesuselayout`.

### Another Ansatz

Maybe using the package bashful wrong.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bashful}

\begin{filecontents}{temp}
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages=-]{page1.pdf}
    \includepdf{page2.pdf}
    \includepdf{page3.pdf}
    \includepdf{page4.pdf}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\bash{ shopt -s nullglob; pdflatex temp.tex; done; } 
\END

\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x2]{temp.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By loading `pgfpages` before `pdfpages`, it works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper]

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{page1.pdf}
\includepdf{page2.pdf}
\includepdf{page3.pdf}
\includepdf{page4.pdf}
\end{document}
```